# Is it possible to subclass Android apps?

Tags: android, plugins, subclass, spy

I want to develop a plugin for an existing app, that doesnt support plugins (Whatsapp for example). On a Windows system this would be very easy, since I can subclass and spy on existing window messages or add new ones, making it possibly to alter the behaviour of any application during run-time.

Would something like that be possible on Android too? Or does its security model prevent interaction between my plugin and the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible on Android.

You cannot write plugins for other apps that are not designed to support them.